# A technician injected malware into my computer without my knowledge

Tags: software, security

So this fixer that I asked to fix my busted front audio ports injected my PC with KMS-R@in in order to get rid of the activate windows watermark without my consent/knowledge, and it gave me Floxif.E and Floxif.H, and updated the drivers to fix the back ports, which wasn't even what I asked him for, is there any legal action I can do to make him take responsibility?

By the way, his store's affiliated with/backed by ASUS.

Comment: In what way were the audio ports "busted"? Was this a hardware or software problem?

Answer (score 2):

All this computer related stuff is really irrelevant. What is relevant is that he was supposed to fix a device of yours, and damaged it in the process. Usually you have the right to get your device back undamaged, and fixed, so it is most likely that the store is responsible for fixing your computer free of charge, this time properly.

Anti-hacking laws most likely don't cover this, because what he did wasn't unauthorised. He was authorised to fix the problem, including by fixing some software, so breaking your computer while trying to fix it isn't unauthorised hacking into your computer.

Comment: I disagree that this action was authorised. Even if the "busted" ports had a software problem the engineer was not authorised to install malware. Also it sounds like the engineer broke Windows copy-protection, which is illegal and therefore cannot be authorised.

Comment: It's definitely authorised. For example, a shop worker who operated the shops computer for printing lottery tickets (as her job) and printed out about 1,000 tickets every week for herself without paying was judged to be _authorised_ to do this - what she did was just theft, not computer hacking. Or a police officer who uses a police database to spy on his ex-girlfriend's new boyfriend; illegal but not computer hacking if he was authorised to use this database as part of his job.

Comment: Programmers with authorisation to install software are routinely found guilty of computer misuse when they install malware. E.g. https://www.computerworld.com/article/2551740/it-worker-jailed-for-creating-logic-bomb.html. Google for "logic bomb" for more cases.